# Nuget Packages "Auto-Update"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget

So, apparently i missed EF 6.0.1 and 6.0.2 before knowing about 6.1 a couple days after the release and that got me wondering, is there a way to be automatically notified that among the packages installed in my solutions, packages X,Y and Z have updates?

Answer (score 1):

are you asking for push notification kind of feature? Right now NuGet does not support automatic notifying package updates; users have to manually go to updates tab to check for updates.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick heads-up: MyGet now offers functionality that should help you with this scenario.
You can create a MyGet feed with the packages you want to monitor for updates and get an email when updates become available.

http://blog.myget.org/post/2014/09/23/Notifications-let-you-know-when-a-package-is-updated.aspx